# Needing to count specific values on a report

Tags: ms-access, report, devexpress

I have an unbound text box in the report footer with expression `=Count(IIf([vwPetBreed]="Bichon Frise",1))` with a summary of count running on the report.

When I run the report I get a sum of the total of the report instead of just the couple that matches the criteria.

I have used `=Sum(IIf())` as well only to get the total of all of them.

The only times I can get a different outcome is if:

1. I change the summary to none, I will get on the report `=Count(IIf(Boston Terrier="Bichon Frise",1))`, or replace Boston Terrier with the breed of the last dog on the report.
2. I change the summary to page, I will get "0"
3. I change the summary to group, I will get "?"

[image: ScrnSht_SumIIf_Dsgnr]
[image: ScrnSht_SumIIf_Rprt]

Comment: The expression in item 1. makes no sense and should error.

Comment: `=SUM(IIf([vwPetBreed]="Bichon Frise",1,0))` should work. Show some sample data then expected output

Comment: @June7 Item 1 is not the expression, it is what I am getting on the report

Comment: @Harun24HR I added a screen shot of the designer showing how the text box assembled and a screen shot of what I am getting back on the report.

Comment: Still makes no sense to me. I cannot replicate issue. Might post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis.

Comment: one way is to set the control source of the textbox to a function that calculates the value you need.  first make sure that theTextBox.RunningSum is off (0).  Then calculate the value you need from the tables rather than the form.  For instance DCount("vwPetBreed", "NameofAppropriateTableorQuery", "vwPetBreed = 'Bichon Frise')  note the single quotation marks around the string variable

Comment: @mazoula unfortunately this isn't my program, I'm just the end user, so I am limited to what table and queries are available to me in the editor. Without being able to add a dcount() into a table, I'm stuck trying to do it in the report and having no luck at getting it to conditionally count and sum.

Comment: if you happen to be able to write your own queries then select all from the relevant table or query.  then add a calculated field to your new query which is that dcount expression.  Then base the report on your new query.